# How to move images one by one in a row?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I am developing a website in asp.net.in that I want to move 'x' number of images
in a row. I will explain the scenario.consider I have 5 images just numbered as 1,2,3,4,5.
initially it is in an order 1 2 3 4 5.and after 10seconds it's in this order 2 3 4 5 1 and after another 10 seconds  order is 3 4 5 1 2.

Can any one help me to code this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont want a solution in Javascript? does it have to be C# with CSS?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: @SonerGönül you edited question , why not you removed how to from title as well as question marks. Its also expected from you sir .

Comment: no.i don't tried anything so far.i don't know the logic for this.can u please help me.

Comment: Show this link http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ it can help you.

Comment: Can anyone have other idea to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something like an image slider? or something like a carousel?

You need jquery for it check this [link](http://www.htmldrive.net/categorys/show/2/Slideshow-Scroller) it has different examples of image slideshow and scroller. I also has an instruction how use it.